# How to show list when click on textfield like search

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to implement search on list. I need to show sorted list when user click on textfield

I have a simple text field like this

```
Container(
  width: Width * 0.92,
  child: TextFormField(
    onChanged: (value) {},
    onSaved: (value) {},),
),
```

What i need to achive is this

Here is simple input

[image]

On type few search word it will open this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try to look into this, [material_floating_search_bar](https://pub.dev/packages/material_floating_search_bar), modify the builder for what you want to display while searching:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    // This is handled by the search bar itself.
    resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
    body: Stack(
      fit: StackFit.expand,
      children: [
        buildMap(),
        buildBottomNavigationBar(),
        buildFloatingSearchBar(),
      ],
    ),
  );
}

Widget buildFloatingSearchBar() {
  final isPortrait = MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.portrait;

  return FloatingSearchBar(
    hint: 'Search...',
    scrollPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16, bottom: 56),
    transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 800),
    transitionCurve: Curves.easeInOut,
    physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
    axisAlignment: isPortrait ? 0.0 : -1.0,
    openAxisAlignment: 0.0,
    width: isPortrait ? 600 : 500,
    debounceDelay: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    onQueryChanged: (query) {
      // Call your model, bloc, controller here.
    },
    // Specify a custom transition to be used for
    // animating between opened and closed stated.
    transition: CircularFloatingSearchBarTransition(),
    actions: [
      FloatingSearchBarAction(
        showIfOpened: false,
        child: CircularButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.place),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ),
      FloatingSearchBarAction.searchToClear(
        showIfClosed: false,
      ),
    ],
    builder: (context, transition) {
      return ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
        child: Material(
          color: Colors.white,
          elevation: 4.0,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: Colors.accents.map((color) {
              return Container(height: 112, color: color);
            }).toList(),
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}
```